# Qt QFileInfo.lastModified() Mac OSX bug?

Tags: macos, qt

I am developing an app for Mac and Windows with Qt. I am monitoring changes to Folder X. When a file is copied from somewhere to Folder X, I read its lastModified() date. On Windows it shows the original file's last modified date of the file, which is expected. However, on Mac it returns the Current DateTime. When I rename the file, after it has been copied to Folder X, I get the original file's last Modified date on both Windows and Mac.

So why does Qt on Mac return current DateTime when the file is copied, and returns original file's modified time after I rename the file?

Comment: Ok, on a little more testing on Windows and Mac, I observed the following: When a file is copied into a folder that is being watched, only one signal is emitted and that is when the file is created. No signal is emitted when the OS finishes writing the file. Is there a workaround to it?

Answer (score 0):

date timestamps are not reliable enough to implement a folder monitoring system, as you've implied above.

i've have spent a few months writing a reliable folder monitoring system on both mac and windows. turned out each required completely different strategies.

on mac: each file and folder can be uniquely identified with an inode number (look in <sys/stat.h>), this number can then used for diff'ing a folder structure to determine changes.

on win: windows also has stat, however this number does not persist and thus cannot be used. i created a solution that uses ReadDirectoryChanges which is a part of the windows api.